# Pandas Series - Trouble Dropping First Value

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm having trouble dropping the first NaN value in my Series.

I took the difference of the normal Series to the shifted Series of 1 period. This is how I calculated it:

```
x[c] = x[c] - x[c].shift(periods=1)
```

When i try to drop the first value using these methods:

- x[c].drop(labels=[0])
- x[c].dropna()
- x[c].iloc[1:]

It doesn't work for me in the reassignment

```
# these are not used all together, but separately
x[c] = x[c].dropna()
x[c] = x[c].drop(labels=['1981-09-29'])
x[c] = x[c][1:]
print(x[c])
```

```
Date
1981-09-29         NaN
1981-09-30   -0.006682
1981-10-01   -0.014575
1981-10-02   -0.004963
1981-10-05   -0.004963
```

However, when I call the drop or dropna function in a print statement, it works!

```
print(x[c].dropna())
```

```
Date
1981-09-30   -0.006682
1981-10-01   -0.014575
1981-10-02   -0.004963
1981-10-05   -0.004963
1981-10-06   -0.005514
```

It doesn't matter what method, I just want to get rid of the first element in my Series.
Pls help.

Answer (score 1):

The dataframe has multiple series where if I tried reassigning just one series, it would still give me an NaN. This is because Series need to be of the same length in a dataframe. Therefore I need to call dropna on the dataframe after the calculation is performed

Answer (score 0):

Try this?

```
x[c] = x[c].dropna(inplace=True)
print(x[c])
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

If you know it is the first element you don't want, the simplest way is to use `series.iloc[1:, :]` or `dataframe.iloc[1:, :]`.